# Eclipse RCP: No application id has been found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm attempting to create an Eclipse RCP application for the first time and so am following the Vogella tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

Per the steps I've created a new Eclipse 4 Application Project using all the default settings, yet when I click on "Launch an Eclipse application" I get an exception. In the error log it lists multiple bundles that could not be resolved and then at the end of the log there is a RuntimeException: No application id has been found.

I have not varied at all from the steps listed in the tutorial/defaults. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 56):

Shortly after posting, I found the specific magical incantation to fix this.

What you need to do is go to your Run Configurations (Run -> Run Configurations). Select the Plug-ins tab and then hit "Add Required Plug-ins". Apply, then Run, and it should work now.

Interestingly enough, it seems to forget this change with some regularity (bug here) and so you may need to do this often before launching :-(

Comment: I had the same problem, and your answer worked for me.  Hooray for people answering their own questions.

Comment: Your answer made my day ! Now I am able to get that empty window…

Comment: Same problem here, and it is true that eclipse forget this change constantly.

Answer (score 17):

I added a list of common problems with starting your product to the tutorial mentioned. Find it here: [Eclipse RCP checklist for common launch problems](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#checklist-for-common-launch-problems)

Please note that modifying the launch configuration is the wrong solution, as your application will fail starting after the export.

Comment: Lars, one more possible reason for "No application id found" error after upgrading to Eclipse Mars was that the id for launching the IDE product has changed to: "org.eclipse.platform.ide"; maybe you can add that to your list.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the result of using a different version of eclipse (not sure). I hadf the same error. When I tried to alter the run config as described, I found no button, checkbox or anything else that stated "Add required plug-ins". What I did find, however, was a drop down list at the top of the plug-ins tab.

Launch with:

1. all workspace and enabled target plug-ins
2. plug-ins selected below only
3. features selected below only

Mine was set to option 2. I switched to option 1 and clicked "Apply". The error went away, though the resulting RCP window didn't contain the expected list... but I suspect that's another problem altogether.

Comment: My mistake... My run configuration window was too small. The button "Add required plug-ins" is to be found on the right. Lars Vogel does mention this config-option ... sadly, after the point in the tutorial where one first attempts to run the app. Anyway, selecting option 2 - plug-ins selected below only - does work. If you cannot see the "Add required plug-ins" button, then look for a scroll bar at the bottom of the pop-up window.

Answer (score 2):

I clicked the "Add Required Plug-ins" button but for some reason, it did not solve the "No application id has been found" problem.

What worked for me is the solution found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/155457/), which is:

- Go 'Run > Run Configurations...'
- Choose your run configuration
- Click on 'Plug-ins' tab
- Add plug-ins below:

org.eclipse.core.net

org.eclipse.ui.ide.application

Answer (score 0):

For those who cannot run even after adding all required plugins, I got this error also when the **JRE System Library** configured in *Run Configurations* was not satisfying the minimum execution environment of the plugin (--> *plugin.xml* || *Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment* in manifest).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Neils solution is forgotten by Eclipse is, that Eclipse overrides the Run Configuration when ever you launch your product from the *.product file. Therefore the solution is to adapt the dependencies in the *.product file instead of the Run Configuration. Moreover I would recommend to always launch Eclipse RCP projects from the *.product file, to avoid problems with changed configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing that worked for me is using eclipse Photon ...so check the version that supports.

Answer (score 0):

After some try and error, I found that I had some problems with the "Run Configurations".

It is managable through this steps:

1. Right-Click on your project's top-most folder inside the Package Explorer
2. Run as
3. Run Configurations...
4. Left-Click on the list's item "Eclipse Application"
5. From that hierachical-tree-like view you could see one or more entry [one is the main Eclipse instance [called with no great fantasy "Eclipse Application"], the others, if any, are the other Eclipse's instances you wish to run]. You should have at least a second ones to run into this whole problem =)
6. Search the "Program to Run" section inside the "Main" tab.
7. Select the radiobutton "Run a product" and write in the textfield the same program's name you find in the entry "Eclipse Application" mentioned in the step 5 [in my case, it is "org.eclipse.platform.ide"].
8. Click on "Apply" and then "Run"
9. Enjoy :D